# Laravel 5.4 sometimes uses different database credentials

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Laravel 5.4 randomly (sometimes not always, or even frequently) tries to connect to a database using the default forge credentials...

I've changed the .env variables to my local MySQL Server already... and as I said it ONLY happens SOMETIMES (rarely)...

I'm able to force the issue to happen by spamming an ajax request that I created.

I did NOT tell Laravel to use a secondary database connection anywhere (unless there's an alternate connection by default when you first install).

Here's the error.

> QueryException in Connection.php line 647: 
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045]
>   Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL:
>   select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = 2 limit 1)

Comment: Can you please show the route your code takes? api.php -> controller -> model query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I had that problem and solved by typing in terminal:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

As I think it happens because sometimes it can't read `.env` file.

Comment: Yes, you should always do this. It merges all your config files into a single minified file and also avoids rereading the config files multiple times per request.